# how to run php in visiual studio code when xampp will install?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp

when PHP file will created in visual studio code
error message will be generated
i install all PHP related extension in vs code

error message screenshot in vs code
[image: error message screenshot in vs code]

Comment: You need to install phpcs (which is a package, not an extension). Read more about how here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs or here http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2017/03/installing-php7-composer-and-codesniffer-on-windows10-for-vscode/

Answer (score 0):

This error message has nothing to do with running PHP code. According to the dialogue you've installed the [phpcs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs) extension (emphasis mine):

> This **linter plugin** for Visual Studio Code provides an **interface to [phpcs](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/)**. It will be used with files that have the “PHP” language mode.

… but didn't complete the installation instructions:

> Before using this plugin, you must ensure that `phpcs` is installed on
>   your system. The preferred method is using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for both
>   system-wide and project-wide installations.

The tool name is actually PHP_CodeSniffer (phpcs is the name of one of the commands it provides) and you can find more comprehensive instructions in its [Github project](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer).

In any case you would still not done yet since you still need to configure the rules you want PHP_CodeSniffer to enforce. E.g., to enforce PSR-2 you can create a file called `phpcs.xml` in your project root:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My project coding style">
    <rule ref="PSR2"/>
    <file>.</file>
</ruleset>
```